# YouTube or Firefox started showing the Windows 10 media pop-up. How can you get rid of it?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, youtube, volume-mixer

As of Sep. 23-24, 2020, either Firefox or YouTube suddenly started spamming the Windows 10 media volume control pop-up, which takes up half the screen.  Since I am on my work laptop, just to be on the safe side, I'll point to a YouTube video from earlier this year that addresses this with Chrome:

[FIX!!! How To Dismiss Windows 10 Media Volume Control Pop up for Google Chrome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCpQhjWbOpU)

The tiny little volume level bar is perfectly okay; it's the other pop-up beside it, which takes half the screen, that is extremely annoying.  How do you get rid of this anti-user deterrent, when you're on Firefox and YouTube (not Chrome or Edge)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Type `about:config` on the address bar.
2. Click "Accept the Risk and Continue", optionally click Show All.
3. On the search box, type `media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled`, set it to false. Restart Firefox.

The popup will no longer be shown. Done on Firefox version 81.0 (64-bit).

[image]

Comment: Setting `media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled` to `false` also disables ability to control video/music by using previous/next and play/pause keyboard keys